# Need to Store Data in SqlAzure and Table Storage in single transaction.?

Tags: azure

I have an scenario for my application?
  I need to store the History data in table Storage and Main Data in Sql Azure.
i.e If an update happens for the Data ,the History data should move to Azure Table Storage and newly modified data should be updated in Sql Azure in Single transaction.if any problems occurs in any one database system,it should get reverted.

and aslo do let me know the advantage and disadvantage of using the above methodology:[Store Data in SqlAzure and Table Storage in single transaction]

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is, **you can't**. There's no concept of in-built distributed transactions here. Also table storage has limited transaction support.

Here's what I would suggest: Rely on triggers in SQL Server and copy the old data in your SQL Server table to another table (let's call it backup table) in the same SQL Server using these triggers. Then have a background process poll this backup table and push the data in table storage. Once the data is pushed into table storage, remove the items from the backup table.